# ss multiselect dropdown dispaly and store as name instead of IDs using AngularTS

Tags: angular, typescript

```
enter code here <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="categoryOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="data.categoryArray" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" ></ss-multiselect-dropdown> 
export class HospitalCreateComponent implements OnInit {categoryOptions :IMultiSelectOption[];
this.categoryOptions = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Child' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Adult' },
    ];
```

Right now my selected option values are stored as Id's only.I would like to save name instead of Id's.I am new to angular and stackoverflow.Please give suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow, 
call an onchange function in your ts file and console.log your ngModel
as ngModel gives you the value which is been selected. by that, you can manipulate the values you need.

`onChange() {
        console.log(this.ngModelValue);
    }`

Comment: Hi Kale,Thanks for reply.I have defined as [(ngModelValue)]="data.categoryArray" and call an onchange function.but I got issues as Can't bind to 'ngModelValue' since it isn't a known property of 'ss-multiselect-dropdown'.Please reslove my issues.

Comment: use only [(ngModel)] not  [(ngModelValue)] ,
 [(ngModelValue)] is not a property of angular but it is property of ss-dropdown